# why do running from yellowbrick.target import FeatureCorrelation results in sklearn.metrics.classification error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, yellowbrick

My Goal is to avoid the warning message below

What I did

```
house_data = pd.read_csv('datasets/house_data_processed.csv')
target = house_data['price']
features = house_data.drop('price', axis=1)
features.columns
from yellowbrick.target import FeatureCorrelation
feature_names = list(features.columns)
```

Warning Msg

> /Users/georgeng/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:144 FutureWarning: The sklearn.metrics.classification module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.metrics. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.metrics is now part of the private API.
>     warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)

Question - I didn't use sklearn in the offending statement above why would the warning msg implied I used sklearn.metrics.classification?

Thnks for your help.
George

Comment: Are you sure you copied your code snippet correctly, When I run it, I'm getting a syntax error. I would also recommend adding sklearn to your tags.

Comment: @WyattBlue thanks for your comment. I've corrected the code and added sklearn to my tag.

Comment: `yellowbrick` uses `sklearn`. You can send this problem to author of `yellowbrick` and ask him to change code. Python has also module `warnings` to control which warning will be displayed but you would have to use `Google` to find details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `sklearn` directly but `yellowbrick` uses it.

Run only this line to see it

```
 from yellowbrick.target import FeatureCorrelation
```

Send this problem to `yelolowbrick` author and ask him to change code.

At this moment you can use module `warnings` to filter warnings

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

from yellowbrick.target import FeatureCorrelation
```